# Cannot log in using Google OpenID on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, openid, firefox, google-openid, login

I cannot log in to stackoverflow.com using the Google OpenID service on Firefox 12, Mac OS Lion. I *can* log in on Chrome. I *can* log in to Meta.

The steps I'm doing to log in:

- Click "log in"
- Select Google OpenID
- Fill in email and password on log in page
- Get back to Stack Overflow
- A notification appears 'welcome back dombesz'
- On the top bar, instead of my username, I still see the "log in" link.
- Hitting refresh still shows the "log in" link.

Comment: This happened to me a couple of times. And every time it was because I had imported settings from Chrome to Firefox. I had to delete the cookie, not just clearing cache.

Comment: How ironic that I couldn't log in to StackOverflow and this closed question on meta solved my problem!  Proving once again that closed questions are often the best questions....

Comment: Well, imho this question is not too localized, a lot of us is using Firefox on mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing the cache solved the issue. [Here is how to clear the cache on Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/clear-cache-delete-temporary-files-fix-issues)

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows 7. Arch Linux worked just fine. I tried clearing the cache without any luck. However, clearing cookies did do the trick! (thanks for the tip)

Answer (score 11):

For me, clearing the cache did not solve the issue, but clearing the stack exchange cookies did.

Look [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored) for instructions on how to clear cookies from individual websites.

(When I did this, I cleared the cookies for stackexchange, stackoverflow, and superuser.)

Comment: This is really working! I cannot believe I couldn't log in into stackoverflow for about 3 months!